# Netbeans PHP - add/remove curly braces plugin/shortcut

Tags: php, plugins, netbeans, shortcut, curly-braces

I love short if statements without braces (PHP) like

```
if ($x === $y)
  echo $z;
```

If I want to add a few lines (maybe just temporary for debugging) I have to manually add the braces. Is there a plugin for netbeans that does that via shortcut, something like "toggle (add/remove) previous statement braces"?

Comment: I can't answer your netbeans question, but curly braces are your friend!  If you've ever run JS through JSLint you soon learn to use them all the time.  That's exactly the reason you should be using curly braces just incase you want multiple lines, your conversion factor is a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I got for now are two macros

### Add Curly-Braces:

```
caret-end-line caret-begin-line "{" insert-break
```

### Remove Curly-Braces:

```
caret-up caret-end-line remove-word-next selection-match-brace cut-to-clipboard remove-line remove-word-previous insert-break paste-from-clipboard caret-up caret-end-line
```

Cursor position has to be in the line of code I want to add/remove braces.