# Is there a way to add braces automatically for if-else single line blocks in netbeans 8.2 (PHP)?

Tags: php, formatting, netbeans-8, code-formatting

I am using `Netbeans 8.2` for my `PHP` project. It was an already build one. When code, I saw so many areas where using `if-else` conditions without braces like below.

```
if(1<2) 
    echo 'yes';
else 
    echo 'no';
```

I don't like this syntax and want to change them to

```
if(1<2){
    echo 'yes';
} else { 
    echo 'no';
}
```

**Is there any inbuilt option or custom plugin to do the same?**

Comment: Are you looking for a language-specific solution, or are you looking for something more general?

Comment: @skomisa, I am looking for PHP programming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netbeans code format braces in PHP single line statements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13801657/2985643), though no solution is offered unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue. Added `php-cs-fixer` to `Netbeans`. And it fixed the issue. `php-cs-fixer` will fix coding standard issues. So the above mentioned is a coding standard issue and `php-cs-fixer` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to automatically correct all if-else statements missing a brace in a single pass, but the functionality to automatically add missing braces on an individual basis for PHP source is built in to NetBeans:

First ensure that `if-else` statements without braces are reported:

- **Tools > Options > Editor > Hints > Language > PHP**.
- Ensure *If-Else Statements must Use Braces* is checked.
- Select the appropriate severity level (*Error*, *Warning*, etc.) and click **OK**.

[image: IfElseBracesOption]

Then build your project containing `if-else` statements without braces:

- I chose to report missing `if-else` braces as errors, so errors were reported on the line following `if` and also on the line following `else` for the PHP code in the screen shot below:
- Placing the cursor on the offending line shows a tooltip with the message *If-Else Statements Must Use Braces*:

[image: tooltipPrompt]

- Press *Alt-Enter* and you will be prompted *Add Braces*.
- Press *Enter* and the braces will be added automatically, and the cursor positioned on the following line:

[image: bracesAdded]

- Note that the braces were only added for the `if` statement, but the associated error is now gone.
- You have to go through the same process again to correct the `else` statement.

This approach is not ideal, but it is reliable, and you only need to got through the exercise once.